# Conflito de codificação usando Tinker e Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou aprendendo a usar Laravel e agarrei em um problema de encoding. Estou tentando usar o **tinker** para inserir dados nas minhas tabelas, e lá estou recebendo o seguinte erro quando tento incluir um novo post:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA1tulo ...' for column 'title' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Título 1, Corpo do primeiro post, 2017-10-09 14:58:40, 2017-10-09 14:58:40))'
```

Minha migration responsável pela tabela **posts** está assim:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // $table->charset = 'utf8';
            // $table->collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

Estou utilizando Windows 10, e o para rodar os comandos do Laravel estou usando o programa **cmder**. Segue um exemplo de inserção de post que tento fazer:

```
$post = new App\post();
$post->title = 'Título 1';
$post->body = 'Corpo do primeiro post';
$post->save();
```

Alguém saberia me dizer o que posso fazer para a inserção de palavras com acento funcionar?

Edit: Segue um print do que aparece no cmder:
[image: Erro no cmder]

Answer (score 1):

Essa é complicada. Eu também tenho problemas com acentos usando o `tinker`.
Nos testes rápidos que faço usando o `tinker`, eu não uso mais acentos.

No StackOverflow em Inglês, achei o seguinte tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458520/laravel-eloquent-not-receiving-accented-characters-from-sqlite-database

Nele, o usuário **Van Niewelt** diz que o problema é o CMD (linha de comando), o qual não lida muito bem com acentos. Apesar do tópico comentar o uso de acentos no SQLite, também se aplica ao Postgres (BD que mais utilizo) e, consequentemente, os demais. Acredito que seja verdade mesmo, pois já tentei usar o Git Bash e o CMD do Windows, mas ambos dão o mesmo problema com acentuação.

Comment: Mas o exemplo dele não passa pelo CMD, claro que você pode estar correto, mas só se o exemplo do autor da pergunta não for real e ele não passou os detalhes corretos.

Comment: Bem observado. Imaginei que o que ele postou após a migration foi uma sequencia de comandos do `tinker`. Como já passei por isso, imaginei que seria algo assim. Mas vamos esperar o autor esclarecer.

Comment: O problema acontece apenas no CMD, via tinker pessoal. Quando executo o mesmo código, diretamente nas páginas, fica tudo ok. Engraçado que em outra máquina, pedi um amigo que fizesse o mesmo teste, e no computador dele funcionou. É como se o meu ambiente estivesse produzindo este conflito de codificação. Cheguei a criar um projeto do zero e repeti o teste, e nada, tudo na mesma. Poderia ser alguma configuração do meu wamp, meu sistema operacional, ou alguma coisa externa desse tipo interferindo?

Answer (score 1):

O erro:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value

Indica que a tabela não aceita o tipo de caractere, se realmente esse seu exemplo for real:

```
$post = new App\post();
$post->title = 'Título 1';
$post->body = 'Corpo do primeiro post';
$post->save();
```

e no caso o `title` não veio do CMD e ainda sim o erro ocorre é porque o script (Controller/Model) não foi salvo na codificação correta, então abra o script em um editor/processador de texto avançado como SublimeText ou notepad++ e salve o documento com o formato **UTF-8 sem BOM**, se tudo estiver correto, então o problema foi no momento que criou a tabela a primeira vez, então talvez tenha que alterar manualmente no banco, por exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE [NOME_DA_TABELA_AQUI] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general;
```

Agora se o exemplo que você postou é irreal `$post->title = 'Título 1';` e na verdade o acento só falha quando os dados veem pelo Tinker, então provavelmente é uma outra falha, se for o caso poste o exemplo correto.

Comment: Guilherme acho que o problema está além da codificação do editor e do banco. Meu banco e minhas tabelas estão em utf8_unicode_ci. O meu editor também está com a codificação utf8. Quando executo diretamente no código o que coloquei no tinker, funciona o insert e vai com acentuação normalmente pro banco. Tudo ok. Só tenho o problema no CMD pelo tinker. Tentei utilizar outro aplicativo além do CMDER e ainda continua o problema. O chcp da página está 850, quando mudo pra 65001 o insert funciona mas no lugar do acento ou qualquer caractere especial fica o símbolo \0. Alguma ideia?

Comment: @churros então o tal exemplo que você postou na pergunta é irreal e não condiz, ou seja sempre faça exemplos conforme a falha. Depois do print da sua imagem acho que agora ficou claro, eu vou efetuar os testes aqui e baixar o cmder e te aviso.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção Guilherme, qualquer novidade, estamos aí. Só um último detalhe, não sei se você viu minha outra resposta, mas eu tentei o mesmo procedimento em outra máquina no escritório onde trabalho e não tive este problema de codificação. Pode ser que você também não tenha.